# How do you not match on an optional group following a missing optional group in Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

Disclaimer: Regex makes me feel stupid. I know I am not good at it, no need to tell me.

I have this regular expression

```
tags/?(?<tagName>[a-z0-9\\-]*
```

that matches on:

- "tags"
- "tags/"
- "tags/tagname"

which is what I want, but it also matches on "tags123" which I don't want.

I do see the issue: I have made the forward slash optional which I need to match on "tags", but I don't know how to make it so that the next group is disqualified from matching if the previous optional group is missing (not sure that it the best way to put that).

Any assistance on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use an optional non capturing group `(?:...)?`:

```
tags(?:/(?<tagName>[a-z0-9-]*))?
```

note that with this syntax the slash is no more optional in the non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\btags(?:/(?<tagName>[a-z0-9-]*))?\b
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pD4wD9)